# Oracle if value to be inserted in foreign key is -1, insert null instead

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a xml script I'm reading from to populate my database with data. One of the nodes in the xml file don't have a idDirector field (the nodes are movies) and so the xml reads a -1  as idDirector and then my stored procedure tries to insert -1 into the fk field and this makes my database returna constraint error : director -1 doesn't exist in Director table. How can I make it so it inserts null instead and make my fk field nullable?

```
CREATE TABLE Film (
    PRIMARY KEY (idFilm),
    FOREIGN KEY (idDirector) REFERENCES Director
);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `CASE` to me, e.g.

```
insert into film (id_film, id_director)
select id_film,
       case when id_director = -1 then null
            else id_director
       end
from ...
```

---

Will it work? Yes:

```
SQL> create table director (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table film (id number primary key, id_director number references director);

Table created.

SQL> insert into director values (100);

1 row created.
```

Inserting -1 fails:

```
SQL> insert into film (id, id_director) values (1, -1);
insert into film (id, id_director) values (1, -1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C0065885) violated - parent key not
found
```

Inserting NULL works:

```
SQL> insert into film (id, id_director) values (1, null);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you, is there something I have to add to make my fk field accept null values or is this already default behavior?

Comment: You're welcome. No, you don't have to do anything. NULL will be accepted. I added an example; have a look.

Comment: @Johnny Bra: A foreign key column can be null as long as you don't explicitly forbid this with a NOT NULL declaration.

Comment: `nullif(id_director, -1)` would also do it.